# Wordpress - How can I loop into two different DIVS without repeating the DIVs

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am having a little trouble trying to figure out how I can accomplish this: I have a container with two colums in it, a right and a left column. Each column will have 3 posts with a short excerpt stacked in it. Ideally I would like to add one into the right and one into the left until it reaches 3 rows of posts(although if that proves to be alot more of a difficult task than I am fine with posting to the first column than the second. I am able to loop through the posts and add them to one column, but I am having trouble figuring out how one will loop into two separate divs, without repeating the divs. Here is how I am attempting it, so far this code will loop into the left column.

The first left side is using the loop to display the title(excerpt will come after) and the right side is just using html. Can anyone help me figure this one out?

```
      <h2>Popular posts</h2>
       <h3>Showing the most popular posts.</h3>

<div class="col4 inner-left">
       <ul class="popular-list">
   <?php
       query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=10&post_type=pop');
       if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li>
             <a href=<?php the_permalink(); ?>><?php the_title(); ?></a>
             <p>Popular post. This is a popular post, it really is.</p>
            </li>
   <?php
       endwhile; endif;
       wp_reset_query();
    ?>          
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="col4 inner-right">
        <ul class="popular-list">
            <li>
              <a href="popularpostlink.php">This is a popular post</a>
              <p>Popular post. This is a popular post, it really is.</p>
            </li>
                 <li>
                  <a href="popularpostlink.php">This is a popular post</a>
                  <p>Popular post. This is a popular post, it really is.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to apply logic for how you want the posts organized *before* you start iterating them.

Here's an example (this isn't functional, just a quick illustration):

```
<?php
$col1 = array();
$col2 = array();
$posts = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six');
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $count++;
    $count % 2 === 1 ? array_push($col1, $post) : array_push($col2, $post);
}
?>
<div class="col-1">
    <?php
    foreach ($col1 as $post) {
        echo '<div class="post">'.$post.'</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="col-2">
    <?php
    foreach ($col2 as $post) {
        echo '<div class="post">'.$post.'</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This produces the output:

```
<div class="col-1">
    <div class="post">one</div>
    <div class="post">three</div>
    <div class="post">five</div>
</div>

<div class="col-2">
    <div class="post">two</div>
    <div class="post">four</div>
    <div class="post">six</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, now the elements of the $posts array are organized in both columns in an alternating fashion.